# запросы в c# с webbrowser

Tags: c#

Есть какой-нибудь сайт, неважно какой, ну как и положено любому сайту, есть куча разных кнопочек, ссылочек и т.д.
Есть минимальный браузер на c# созданный с помощью WebBrowser.
Как обращаться к нужной мне кнопочке на сайте ? Я так пологаю это делается с помощью get и post запросов ? Покажите примерчик какой-нибудь. Еще вопрос, как реагировать на то или иное событие, которое происходит на сайте, как его обрабатывать?

Comment: Я такой вопрос уже видел.

Comment: @Qwertiy - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513473/c-get-post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B - полная копия, даже с "пологаю"

Comment: Да, но ответа я так не получил;(